# Pagination jumps to first page if redraw table using fnClearTable occured in other pages

Tags: php, ajax, pagination, datatables

I created a table using jquery datatable and get the data of the tables from server side using ajax. Here's my code in my js:

```
var runDataTable_example1 = function() {
                    var oTable = $('#sample_1').dataTable({
            "aoColumnDefs" : [{
                "aTargets" : [0]
            }],
            "oLanguage" : {
                "sLengthMenu" : "Show _MENU_ Rows",


            },
            "aaSorting" : [[0, 'desc']],
            "aLengthMenu" : [[5, 10, 15, 20, -1], [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
            ],
            // set the initial value
            "iDisplayLength" : 10,
                        "bFilter": false,
                        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                        "processing": true,
                        "serverSide": true,
                        "ajax": "myjobData.php",
        });

        //$('#sample_1_wrapper .dataTables_filter input').addClass("form-control input-sm").attr("placeholder", "Search");
        // modify table search input
        $('#sample_1_wrapper .dataTables_length select').addClass("m-wrap small");
        // modify table per page dropdown
        $('#sample_1_wrapper .dataTables_length select').select2();
        // initialize select2 dropdown
        $('#sample_1_column_toggler input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
            /* Get the DataTables object again - this is not a recreation, just a get of the object */
            var iCol = parseInt($(this).attr("data-column"));
            var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
            oTable.fnSetColumnVis(iCol, ( bVis ? false : true));
        });
    };
```

I set an interval of 10 seconds so that table could refresh using this code:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   var oTable = $("#sample_1").dataTable();
   oTable.fnClearTable();

},10000);
```

But if I am page number 3 and after 10 seconds the data refresh and jumps to page number 1. How can i avoid it to jump to page number 1 and stay in page 3 even after refresh.

PHP code is just a simple table tag with all headings:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-width" id="sample_1">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th width='10%'>Column_0</th>
                                                    <th width='20%'>Column_1</th>
                                                    <th width='20%'>Column_2</th>
                                                    <th width='10%'>Column_3</th>
                                                    <th width='20%'>Column_4</th>
                                                    <th width='10%'>Column_5</th>
                                                    <th class="hidden-xs" width='10%'>Column_6</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>

                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to save the state to remain on same page. use `"bStateSave": true` .

try something like this

```
var oTable = $('#sample_1').dataTable({
 "bStateSave": true,
 "aoColumnDefs" : [{
            "aTargets" : [0]
        }],
        "oLanguage" : {
            "sLengthMenu" : "Show _MENU_ Rows",


        },
        "aaSorting" : [[0, 'desc']],
        "aLengthMenu" : [[5, 10, 15, 20, -1], [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
        ],
        // set the initial value
        "iDisplayLength" : 10,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax": "myjobData.php",
    });
```

Comment: why "bJQueryUI": true, ??

Comment: @MishraShreyanshu, maybe a result of copy/paste from another code. The idea is to use `bStateSave` or `stateSave`.

Comment: Yes, it's from my older code and I am using this with mobile version so using BJQueryUI. You can skip it.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, I have already mention in my first line of answer what need to use. I was testing OP code with my page and I have used BJQueryUI so the same thing came here.

Comment: @RamSharma I appreciate your help, +1 for bStateSave, but bStateSave not working for pagination, but if I change the record limit or sorting paramenter it works even after reloading the page, but pagination is not setting up.